# validate white spaces in a string using php

Tags: php, string

Validate the user entered in textbox that contains only white spaces.

```
$str = ' ';
$str2 = " abc @ def <etc>";
```

I need to validate the above two strings ,that returns an output for $str is false and $str2 is true.

Comment: \*cough\*`trim`\*cough\*classic\*simple\*cough\*problem\*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it.

```
$isValidString = (bool) strlen(trim($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the trim method:

```
if (trim($str) == "") {
  // empty
}
else {
  // do sg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

```
if(trim($string) == "")
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

1)For just spaces, use str_replace: For ex, $string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);

2)For all whitespace, use preg_replace:

$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);

3)If you just are dealing with excess whitespace on the beginning or end of the string you can use trim(), ltrim() orrtrim() to remove that.